# XML test data for large text element?

Tags: xml, testing

We need to build test data for complex nested XML schema (xsd). We tried with XMLspy, where we have the following situation.

**Here is our .xsd piece.--------------------------**

```
<xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Explanation" type="ExplanationType" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
```

**XSD Type definition ------------------**

```
<xsd:simpleType name="ExplanationType">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>A note field that allows up to 9000 characters</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:restriction base="TextType">
            <xsd:maxLength value="9000"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
```

**Generated test XML via xmlspy**

```
<Explanation>!</Explanation>
```

Even though  element defined as 9000 length, we have only one character (!). How do I get 9000 length string such as

```
**<Explanation>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ……………………………(9000 length)</Explanation>**
```

In my test data (generated xml message) ?

Is there an option to get such thing via xmlspy?

Is there any other tool provide such data?

Comment: Any one review this question? Welcome your suggestion.

Comment: Couldn't you build it with cat?  I'm not sure I understand.  What is your OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your type definition into two files with the first ending with: (caret)xsd:documentation(caret)
and the second beginning with: (caret)/xsd:documentation(caret)

Windows:

```
type preamblefile 9000charfile postfile > testfile
```

Linux:

```
cat preamblefile 9000charfile postfile > testfile
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply/question. This question related to build test XML message that conform with .XSD (XML schema). This will be used to test the services build around XSD. The piece posted as small portion of large XML schema.